# GORM: hasMany of the same domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Just wondering if someone can suggest how the domain class schema should be. I have a domain class called Category, but there can be sub-categories with the same domain (Category). For example, an appliance Toaster can be under category Kitchen, sub-category SmallAppliance.

```
class Category {
   static hasMany = [appliances: Appliance, categories: Category] 
   String name
}

class Appliance {
   static belongsTo = Category
   static hasMany = [categories: Category]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A small tweak needed to the Appliance domain class. Guess it!! :)

We don't need the hasMany relationship in `Appliance` for `categories`. The relationship goes like this:

```
Category --> SubCategory (type of Category) --> Appliance
```

An appliance `belongsTo` the parent category as well as to the `subCategory` which in turn is a `Category` itself. So belongsTo relationship is enough in appliance.

Use Instead:

```
class Appliance {
   static belongsTo = Category
   String name
}

class Category {
    String name
    static hasMany = [appliances: Appliance, subCategories: Category]
}
```

Here is a test case which can make understand things better:

```
//Category
def kitchen = new Category(name: "Kitchen")
kitchen.save()

//Appliance
def toaster = new Appliance(name: "Toaster")
kitchen.addToAppliances(toaster)
kitchen.save()

//Sub Categories
def electrical = new Category(name:  "Electrical")
//Electrical category is a sub category of Kitchen
kitchen.addToSubCategories(electrical)

//Toaster is an appliance of Category Kitchen and Sub Category Electrical
electrical.addToAppliances(toaster)
kitchen.save()

assert kitchen
assert toaster
assert electrical

assert kitchen.appliances.size() == 1
kitchen.appliances.each{assert it.name == 'Toaster'}

assert kitchen.subCategories.size() == 1
kitchen.subCategories.each {assert it.name == 'Electrical'}

assert electrical.appliances.size() == 1
electrical.appliances.each {assert it.name == 'Toaster'}
```

Let know if it is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I see what you mean, just in my case I want to be able to add a product across several categories, not just in one. For example: Toaster in Category Kitchen & subCategory SmallAppliance. Also Toaster in Category Electrical.